AppShortcuts that reference iOS 17 specific AppIntents appear on iOS 16 and lead to crashes
I've got several AppIntents that use iOS 17 specific features and are therefore annotated with @available(iOS 17.0, *). The AppIntent is correctly only listed on iOS 17 in the Shortcuts app and hidden on iOS 16. However, if I reference those AppIntents in an App Shortcut, the AppShortCut also appears on iOS 16, even though the AppIntent is iOS 17 only and even the AppShortcutsProvider is annotated with @available(iOS 17.0, *). When the user taps the App Shortcut on iOS 16, it leads to a crash of the application.
Example Code:
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct HelloIntent:AppIntent
{
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "iOS 17 only AppIntent"
    static var isDiscoverable: Bool = true
    
    @Parameter(title:"Input")
    var input:String
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct PhotoSyncShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        return [
            AppShortcut(
                intent: HelloIntent(),
                phrases: ["\(.applicationName) Hello"],
                shortTitle: "Hello iOS 17",
                systemImageName: "01.circle"
            )
        ]
    }
}

I would appreciate any hint on how to create the AppShortcuts without crashing on iOS 16.

Have you found workaround for this?

Upon further investigation, I believe there is no viable workaround. The issue lies in the way AppIntents and AppShortcuts are handled during compile time. Specifically, they are outputted into a manifest file, which includes a minimum OS version requirement for AppIntents, but not for AppShortcuts.

I found it from other channel. This is indeed issues with Xcode issue. And known issue start from Xcode 15.3. Apple says to add this build flag to your target: ENABLE_APPINTENTS_DEPLOYMENT_AWARE_PROCESSING=NO

ENABLE_APPINTENTS_DEPLOYMENT_AWARE_PROCESSING tackles another issue, that without ENABLE_APPINTENTS_DEPLOYMENT_AWARE_PROCESSING all AppIntents crash on iOS 16, if the target SDK is iOS 15 or lower. The issue above (iOS 17 specific AppShortCuts) is independent form that.
